# Does ever calling `check()` on a capability panic?

Tags: onflow-cadence

According to the docs there is no reference of check panicking in any situation, but I would like to know if there is any edge case where this method could panic rather than returning false.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS, there are currently two cases where `check()` may fail:

- The path leads to a cycle (see https://github.com/onflow/cadence/issues/2264)
- Not sure: The code/type of the stored value is broken and cannot be loaded

Please feel free to open an issue in the Cadence repository if you think this should be changed, and especially why. Thanks!